# Adding additional destination cell in vba code

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below code that copies a range from one sheet and pastes it in a differ sheet and does a calculation (ignores the colored values).

What I want to do is, I want to add additional cells into this code to perform the same function but for a slightly different formula...

The formula I ant to use is given below and the destiantion cells are AH 101 and AH102.

```
 "=PERCENTILE.INC(" & Rng.Address(, , , True) & ",90%)*24"
 "=PERCENTILE.INC(" & Rng.Address(, , , True) & ",50%)*24"
```

This is my entire code:

```
Sub TPNoRed()
 Dim cel As Range
 Dim Rng As Range
 Dim arr As Variant
 Dim i As Long
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 For Each cel In Sheets("TP").Range("A3:D30")
 If cel.Font.Color = 0 Then
 If Rng Is Nothing Then
 Set Rng = cel
 Else
 Set Rng = Union(cel, Rng)
 End If
 End If
 Next cel
 ReDim arr(Rng.count - 1)
 If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
 For Each cel In Rng
 arr(i) = cel
 i = i + 1
 Next cel
 Sheets("TP").Range("AH1").Resize(UBound(arr) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(arr)
 Set Rng = Sheets("TP").Range("AH1:AH" & Sheets("TP").Cells(Rows.count, "AH").End(xlUp).Row)
 Sheets("WBR45").Range("AH103").Formula = "=PERCENTILE.INC(" & Rng.Address(, , , True) & ",99%)*24"
  Sheets("WBR45").Range("AH103").Value =    Sheets("WBR45").Range("AH103").Value
 Sheets("TP").Columns("AH:AH").ClearContents  
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

Comment: Please remember that using indents makes code much easier to read and follow. If you sort this the chances of receiving advice increase. Thanks.

Comment: Am I reading this question correctly?  Are you asking how to repeat the line saying `Sheets("WBR45").Range("AH103").Formula = "=PERCENTILE.INC(" & Rng.Address(, , , True) & ",99%)*24"` and then change `103` to `102` and `99%` to `50%`?

Comment: Not change it...to add additional cells and formula into the same code to do the same function